# Extracting Zip File from public google drive using colab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, dataset, google-colaboratory

I would like to download a dataset from a public google drive folder (saved as a zip).

`url = https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TzwfNA5JRFTPO-kHMU___kILmOEodoBo`

Since I want it to be reproducible by other people, I do not want to copy it to my drive (and preferably also not to mount my drive in the notebook).

How can it be done?

So far I tried:

```
import requests
import io
import zipfile

zip_url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo'

response = requests.get(zip_url)
file_contents = io.BytesIO(response.content)
print(file_contents)
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_contents, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('/content/')  # Replace with your desired extraction path
```

but get this error (and print of "file_contents" before):

```
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ad7efbf27f0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-56d2c8f2bfe8> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 print(file_contents)
     13 # Extract the zip file (if needed)
---> 14 with zipfile.ZipFile(file_contents, 'r') as zip_ref:
     15     zip_ref.extractall('/content/')  # Replace with your desired extraction path

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1334             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1335         if not endrec:
-> 1336             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1337         if self.debug > 1:
   1338             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

and if I try the following way, i get an empty zip file:

```
file_id = '1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo'
download_url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={file_id}'
!wget --no-check-certificate -O '/content/file.zip' 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Content Type returned is html and not a zip file.

```py
import requests
import io

file_id = '1fdFu5NGXe4rTLYKD5wOqk9dl-eJOefXo'
download_url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={file_id}'
response = requests.get(download_url)
print(response.headers.get("Content-Type"))
```

This should tell you what content the server is returning. in this case its text/html which is not a zip file.

Check that the url points to an actual zip file.